pandas/python: Seperate Date and Timestamp and delete duplicates
I have a data set that date and timestamp of createddate and closeddate is in 1 column:
CreatedDate                            ClosedDate
1/1/2023 0:00                        1/13/2023 12:43
1/1/2023 0:10                        1/6/2023 10:43
How to separate the date and timestamp of each createddate and closeddate in a separate column and in order? Like this or you guys can recommend me a better name for that timestamp column
CreatedDate           Timestampcreateddate                ClosedDate             Timestampcloseddate
1/1/2023                       0:00                                         1/13/2023                     12:43
1/1/2023                        0:10                                          1/6/2023                      10:43
Then we find duplicates and missing data to drop it? Reason: checking if any rows have the same CreatedDate is the same as ClosedData. The reason behind this approach is because the data in the Created and Closed date columns are string values which means the values in both columns have to be exactly the same to be deleted which is: if 12/31/2023 11:59:45 PM is in column CreatedDate and ClosedDate then it is deleted
data = data[data['CreatedDate'] != data['ClosedDate']]
We only focus on 1/1/2023 to 12/31/2023 period.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your input is unclear, you should provide a DataFrame constructor. How do you import/create the data in the first place? If you have a single column, better try to solve the problem there rather than fixing if after importing. If you import from CSV, please share a sample of the CSV file. Please read How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Okay, from your question you already have a timeline focus, so let me break it down this way.
So, first you might want to separate the date and timestamp for both the Createdate and the CLosedDate columns though by converting the date time strings to an actual datetime object and then extracting the date and time parts into separate columns. After that you can check the rows for where CreatedDate and ClosedDate are the same then you can remove those rows. Since you want to look at data within 2023, you can do something like this:
import pandas as pd

# first i called the info you gave in the question
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'CreatedDate': ['1/1/2023 0:00', '1/1/2023 0:10'],
    'ClosedDate': ['1/13/2023 12:43', '1/6/2023 10:43']
})

# then you can now convert the CreatedDate n ClosedDate columns to datetime like i suggested earlier
data['CreatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['CreatedDate'])
data['ClosedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['ClosedDate'])

# once you have converted it, you can separate the date and time components too for sorting
data['CreatedDateDate'] = data['CreatedDate'].dt.date
data['CreatedDateTime'] = data['CreatedDate'].dt.time
data['ClosedDateDate'] = data['ClosedDate'].dt.date
data['ClosedDateTime'] = data['ClosedDate'].dt.time

# in my explanation, i said you should also filter the data to 2023 focus, so your data has to only include between first and last day of 2023
start_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2023')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('12/31/2023')
data = data[(data['CreatedDate'] >= start_date) & (data['CreatedDate'] <= end_date)]

# once you have filtered date to just the year you want, you can remove all the rows that has CreatedDate as the same as ClosedDate by doing this:
data = data[data['CreatedDate'] != data['ClosedDate']]

# If you see fit, you might want to drop the original date and time colums, it is not necessary tho, but you can by doing this:
data.drop(columns=['CreatedDate', 'ClosedDate'], inplace=True)

print(data)

If you have any other question, you can ask by replying.
